# How to get the value of a MySQL VARIABLES var?

Tags: mysql, variables, syntax

I need to fetch a scalar value of the MySQL VARIABLE "version". Currently running this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name="version"
```

Is giving me a table like:

```
Variable_name    Value
-------------    -----------
version          5.5.28-log
```

How do I just get the Value cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out how:

```
 select variable_value 
 from information_schema.global_variables
 where variable_name = 'version';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set @x = select @@version;
```

That will set the user variable @x with the current version.

If you want it in a straight select, use

```
select @@version;
```

This generalizes - most system variables are available using the @@ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`version()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_version) function.

```
select version();
```